# How to confirm string type in list structure in Python()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a Leetcode test about keyboard rows, and I don't know the exactly meaning of that(actually I can't run it correctly in pycharm)I don't know why use list[str] can't confirm the type you input is string,and the IDE always pop the error,someone has to help me with this~

```
    class Solution:
        def findWords(self, words: list[str]) -> list[str]:
            set1, set2, set3 = set("qwertyuiop"), set("asdfghjkl"), set("zxcvbnm") 
 #input every row's words
            ans = []
            for i in words:
                t = set(i.lower())
                if t <= set1 or t <= set2 or t <= set3:
                    ans.append(i)
            return ans
    a=list(input())
    b=Solution()
    c=b.findWords(a)
    print(c)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python文件/Python/Leetcode/leetcode.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Solution:
  File "E:/Python文件/Python/Leetcode/leetcode.py", line 10, in Solution
    def findWords(self, words: list[str]) -> list[str]:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable##
```

i have seen many answers about typeeError, i have tried the initialize the definition,but it won't work,actually i don't know what to do

Comment: I am working on a Leetcode test about keyboard rows,and  i dont know the exactly meaning of that(actually i cant run it correctly in pycharm)I don't know why use list[str] can't confirm the type you input is string,and the IDE always pop the error,someone has to help me with this~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the function type signature. You need to import [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def findWords(self, words: List[str]) -> List[str]:
...
```